# Infinite Loop injected into website freezes javascript load

Tags: javascript, loops, google-chrome, code-injection

I want to inject a javascript continuous loop into a website using a javascript injector ([custom javascript for websites](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija/related?hl=en)), and I have this code:

```
for(;;){
document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].click();
}
```

Now, when I run this javascript, the website freezes and refuses to load anymore javascript. Is there a way to run this loop but still allow the website to function normally? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes... give the loop a point of closure. What are you actually trying to achieve? Just clicking on a button repeatedly for an indefinite timeframe?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I need to call the click continuously (or only trigger it when a certain scenario occurs) so I am not sure how to close it. I'm sorry if there is a simple answer, I'm relatively new to programming

Answer (score -1):

you can use HTML5 webworkers for your purpose.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

Comment: I'll give this a look. Thank you!